# Five Buttons One Dropdown List

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to populate a dropdown listbox with a set of five buttons.  The first one works, however the other four do not, as of yet.  If been looking around but due to inexperience I can't seem to put it together.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.  Here is the code I have so far...incomplete.

```
mysql_select_db('Mydb'); 

$place = mysql_query("select * from tblRestaurants order by RestName ASC");
$cuisine = mysql_query("select * from tblCuisine order by CuisineName ASC");
$city = mysql_query("select * from tblCities order by CityName ASC");
$state = mysql_query("select * from tblStates order by StateName ASC");
$zipcode = mysql_query("select * from tblLocations order by ZipCode ASC");


while ($nt= mysql_fetch_assoc($place))
    $arrData[] = $nt;

if(isset($_GET["ajax"]))
{
    echo json_encode($arrData);
    die();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function displayPlace()
{
    $.getJSON("Four.php?ajax=true", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, objRecord) {
            var option=document.createElement("option");
            option.value=objRecord.RestID;
            option.text=objRecord.RestName;
            $("#Doggie").append('<option value="' + objRecord.RestID + '">' + objRecord.RestName + '</option>');
        });
    });

}

function displayCuisine()
{
    $.getJSON("Four.php?ajax=true", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, objRecord) {
            var option=document.createElement("option");
            option.value=objRecord.CuisineID;
            option.text=objRecord.CuisineName;
            $("#Doggie").append('<option value="' + objRecord.CuisineID + '">' +   objRecord.CuisineName + '</option>');
        });
    });

}

    </script>
    <title>SEARCH</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form>
        <button type="button"  onclick="javascript:displayPlace();">Place</button>
        <button type="button"  onclick="javascript:displayCuisine();">Cuisine</button>
        <button type="button"  onclick="javascript:displayCity();" >City</button>
        <button type="button"  onclick="javascript:displayState();">State</button>
        <button type="button"  onclick="javascript:displayZipCode();">Area</button>
        <br /> 

        <select name="Doggie" id="Doggie"></select>

        <br /> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: it this is the exact code you have coded then you have not done coding for the rest of the option that is the reason data is not showing there

Comment: Just to clear up the question... You want to use different buttons to call different java-script functions that fetch JSON data and fill the select list? And only the first button works?

Comment: when ever you will press the cuisine button at that time the same ajax request is called so the respond will not have objRecord.CuisineID in that because in php script you have done coding only for the Places rest all are remaining

Comment: Yes Devon, that is correct.

Comment: Anand, thats the problem.  I am not sure how to proceed further.  I like your switch case idea, but at this point it is not filling the list.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your php code i have tried to explain this using some sample code

and pass one additional parameter of case in the ajax request and then it will work for you

```
$list['place']   =  mysql_query("select * from tblRestaurants order by RestName ASC");
$list['cuisine'] =  mysql_query("select * from tblCuisine order by CuisineName ASC");

foreach($list as $key=>$value){
 while ($nt = mysql_fetch_assoc($list[$key]))
     $list_array[$key] = $nt;
}
if(isset($_GET["ajax"]))
{
   switch($_GET['case']){
       case 'place':
          echo json_encode($list_array['place']);
          break;
       case 'cuisine':
          echo json_encode($list_array['cuisine']);
          break;

   }

   die();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I poped the code in and it doesn't return any results.  This is definitly the idea though.  What could be wrong?